# JPA findAll() not returning everything in a view

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa

We create a view from a series of select statements

```
SELECT d.DLVRB_CD AS ID,
    'DL_GROUP' AS GRP,
    d.DLVRB_NM AS VALU,
    NULL AS DFLT_VALU,
    NULL AS DN
FROM DLVRB d

UNION ALL

SELECT m.MODF_CD AS ID,
    'MD_SELECTION' AS GRP, 
    m.MODF_NM AS VALU,
    NULL AS DFLT_VALU,
    m.MODF_DN AS DN
FROM MODF m

UNION ALL

SELECT m.MODF_CD AS ID,
    'MD_ALL' AS GRP, 
    m.MODF_NM AS VALU,
    NULL AS DFLT_VALU,
    m.MODF_DN AS DN
FROM MODF m

UNION ALL

SELECT v.VAR_CD AS ID, 
    'VA_GROUP' AS GRP, 
    v.VAR_NM AS VALU,
    v.VAR_DFLT_QT AS DFLT_VALU,
    NULL AS DN
FROM VAR v
```

Later on when we try to use JPA findAll() method to return the contents of the View. It is missing some of the the data. specifically it is missing the MD_ALL group (which is the third statement in the code)

The View is generated correctly, as in the data for each select statement is correctly shown. Only when the findAll() is called, the data for the select of 'MD_ALL' is missing.

Interestingly if I swap the MD_SELECTION and the MD_ALL statements, MD_ALL will be returned in the findAll() call and not the MD_SELECTION.

Does findAll() omit data under certain conditions?

Comment: How is the entity defined? What is its ID? Are you sure each row in the view has a distinct ID?

Comment: the Id's are not distinct no. As in the ID's for the MD_Selection and MD_ALL are common.

Would findAll() only return the distinct values?

Comment: Then you have your answer. An entity is identified by its ID. So two distinct  entities of the same type may not have the same ID

Comment: So even if the DB view is create correctly from the above statement, I.e. all the values for all 4 select statements are present in the view.

findAll() will only return the destinct subset?

Comment: Yes, and you just verified it, didn't you? An ID needs to be an ID. If it doesn't identify an entity, it's not an ID anymore.

Comment: I guess I did, I just assumed that findAll() would return ALL.

Thanks for helping

Comment: It will, if you design your entity correctly, and use a real ID, that uniquely identifies the entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User JB Nizet, Is correct.

Altho the view was created correctly and contained all the information contained across all the tables, JPA's Find all will only return a distinct list of entities.

In my case, some of the Id's (although Unique within there own tables) where not Unique once combined within the view and JPA rightly and correctly when fetching the list of entities from the view it will ignore any subsequent entity it finds with a duplicate ID when reading the results set.

The fix in my case was to create its own unique ID field within the View. findAll() then retrieves everything as it does not have any entities with duplicate Id's

Answer (score -1):

I think the issue with findAll()  method in JPA not returning data could because of 1-M mapping in the database.

Comment: Hi thanks for answering, I have added the answer myself, I never got around to adding one.